# How to remove all occurence of a character when losing focus of a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create in jquery a function that once a user tabs out of a control or finishes typing in the textbos, removes the # character from the field,

```
 $('[id$=txtClient]').keyup(function (){

}
```

First I dont know how to remove it, and should I do it in the keyup? or in another event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('[id$=txtClient]').keyup(function (){
    var $el = $(this); // the text element
    var text = $el.val();
    text = text.split("#").join("");//remove occurances
    $el.val(text);//set it back on the element
});
```

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGyAK/)

- [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the input field's value
- [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on "#" and then [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it on ""
- Place back in element
- Happens on [key up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup)

Comment: but its ok on the keyup? or another event?

Comment: @LuisValencia KeyUp is ok, I've added a demo so you'll be able to play with it and see the behavior. If you have any questions about the code, or parts you'd like me to clarify, please let me know. KeyUp binds to when a key is lifted, it'll happen 'instantly' and not when the element loses focus.

Comment: @Lilith2k3 Good question! Replace would require a RegExp which would require OP to know regular expressions or use code he might not fully understand. split/join is also faster, and what's happening is dead simple. See http://jsfiddle.net/prt9L/

Comment: For a simple replace you could go with "bla#bla".replace("#","") no regexp required.

Comment: @Lilith2k3 Right, `.replace` with a string first argument only replaces the _first_ occurrence which is satisfactory for the case you just mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `keyup` is the event you want.  Instead I would recommend using `blur`, which tracks when the element loses focus.  Otherwise the user will just be unable to type `#`, which might be somewhat frustrating.  Then you can use `replace()` to remove the `#` characters:

```
$('[id$=txtClient]').blur(function() {
     $(this).val( $this.val().replace(/#/g, '') );
});
```

The code in the function sets the element's text to be its existing text, but with each `#` replaced by an empty string using a regex.  (Thanks to Benjamin Gruenbaum for pointing out a flaw with my first use of `replace()`).

Comment: This will fail if the user enters `"asd#asd#adsa#"` for example, since when using `blur` the change is not instant, you have to deal with multiple occurrences of '#' in the string. That's not how `.replace` works. If you want to use it, you need to pass a regex first param with a global flag.

Comment: It seems to be an `<input>` field, so do not use `.text()`!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [`blur` event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) which happens when the input loses focus, and then just change the `value` which can be accessed as a property of the input (for a jQuery wrapper: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)):

```
$("[id$=txtClient]").blur(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/#/g, "");
});
```